# Horizontal column of buttons, left alligned

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: horizonal column of buttons]

I am trying to create a column of buttons but I want them left aligned.

I have tried many things but am new at css/html5.

Answer (score 0):

Use an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="/images/yourimage.png />Some Text</li>
    <li><img src="/images/yourimage.png />Some Text</li>
    <li><img src="/images/yourimage.png />Some Text</li>
</ul>
```